# Periodically adding one row to DataGridView, but all rows get added at the same time

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, ping

So I've got this code:

```
Ping ping = new Ping();
for(int i = 0; i<= number_of_pings; i++)
{
    PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(address_to_send);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(address_to_send, pingReply.Address, pingReply.RoundtripTime, pingReply.Status);         
}
```

For some reason when its being pumped into a `dataGridView1`, the `dataGridview1` has five (or however number of pings I specify) fields of data pumped to it at once.
What I'm trying to do is have the `dataGridView1` fill up periodically. E.g. after each ping has completed, its output to the `dataGridView1` and the next ping starts and so on.

Ideas?

Comment: Is it really adding all 5 at once?  Or are the pings just happening very quickly?  It looks like very quickly, according to this code.  Do you want the grid to fill up slower?

Comment: Yea, maybe it is just filling up quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the update method of the datagridview after each add row:

```
dataGridView1.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the best solution for your needs is BackgroundWorker.
Define an empty DataTable in your class and put Ping codes into BackgroundWorker_DoWork method. then Add result to DataTable.
When this method completed, BackgroundWorker_WorkerComplete has fired. You should run DoWork method again for next ping.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ping ping = new Ping();

for(int i = 0; i<= number_of_pings; i++)
{
    PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(address_to_send);

    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(address_to_send, pingReply.Address, pingReply.RoundtripTime, pingReply.Status);
    dataGridView1.PerformLayout();
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```